# Input search not working in Edge, IE, or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, django, firefox, search

The search bar works in Chrome and Opera but not in the browsers named above. I suggest it has something to do with the `onsearch="search(event)"`.

[image]

Mozilla say's its not supported and I was wondering if anyone knew of a solution to this issue?

HTML:

```
<input
    type=search
    name=""
    id="filterSearch"
    placeholder="Search for events, seasonal meals or simply list ingredients"
    onsearch="search(event)"
>
```

Comment: [By the sounds of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/search) it looks like it's just a glorified onsubmit (of your form) with extra functionality that sounds like a timed-out onkeyup if the input is a number incrementer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The onsearch event is not supported in Internet Explorer, Firefox or Opera 12 and earlier versions.
Try using onchange,onkeyup etc

```
<input type=search name="" id="filterSearch" placeholder="Search for events, seasonal meals or simply list ingredients" onchange="search(this.id)">
```

Comment: I stated this in the above as I showed Mozilla saying this. Do you have a solution?

Comment: check my above edit,onchange works similar to onsearch